# Blackbird Advanced Content Manager 2 - Get date created/published/modified in php template?

Tags: magento2, cms

I'm using this module '[Blackbird Advanced Content Manager 2](https://www.advancedcontentmanager.com/)' for blog posts.

I want to get the date created / published / modified and output it in the php template.

There is no mention of this anywhere in the [docs](https://www.advancedcontentmanager.com/en/advanced-content-manager-2/documentation/renders-methods). Has anyone worked out a way of doing it?

Such a simple / common / necessary thing for blogs, can't believe there doesn't seem to be a function for it :/ Judging by the lack of information online I'm guessing no one uses this plugin because it's rubbish?

If I try their method to 'get all raw values' 
`$content->getData()`
Annoyingly I always get a 'php memory exhausted' error (Even when I set memory_limit to 50Gb!). So I don't know if there is a 'date' field available in there. I've also searched the module php in app/code looking for any mentions of date variables but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! (gleaned the 'field_identifier' from 'blackbird_contenttype_entity' database table). Derp!

```
$content->getData('created_at');
$content->getData('updated_at');
```